# subscribed value returns undefined in component.ts but value exists in service.ts

Tags: angular, angular-services, google-sheets-api

Here are the contents of my `component.ts` file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleSheetsService } from '../shared/services/googlesheets.service';

@Component({
selector: 'home-component',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  apiPortfolioListEndPoint: string;
  portfolioList: Array<string>;

  constructor (
    private googleSheetsService: GoogleSheetsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiPortfolioListEndPoint = '/home/portfolio';
    this.getImagesFromSheets(this.apiPortfolioListEndPoint);
  }

  getImagesFromSheets(sheetName) {
    this.googleSheetsService.getImages(sheetName)
      .subscribe(photos => {
        console.log(photos);
      });
  }
}
```

and contents of my `service.ts` file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleSheetsService {

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  getImages(sheetName) {
    const apiServerEndPoint = '/api' + sheetName;
    return this.http.get(apiServerEndPoint)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        console.log(res.json());
        res.json();
      });
  }
}
```

res in google sheets service returns an array of values and gets printed out on console but returns undefined when subscribed in my component (i.e. photos returns undefined on console).

`getImages()` calls an API that retrieves data from google spreadsheets.

When I tried to assign photos to the `portfolioList` variable, atom highlights the following error `"Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string[]' "`. it makes sense since they are of different types, photos cannot be assigned to the variable but I cant seem to wrap my head around this problem and how I can go about fixing this.

Any suggestions or directions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the results in the `map`

```
  getImages(sheetName) {
        const apiServerEndPoint = '/api' + sheetName;
        return this.http.get(apiServerEndPoint)
          .map((res: Response) => {
            console.log(res.json());
            /* You need to return the data here*/
            return res.json();
          });
      }
```

Even better

```
/* import these first*/  
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

      getImages(sheetName) {
            const apiServerEndPoint = '/api' + sheetName;
            return this.http.get(apiServerEndPoint)
              .map(this.extractData)
              .catch(this.catchError);
          }

      private extractData(res: Response) {
        return res.json();
      }

      private catchError(error: Response | any) {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server Error");

      }
```

**Edit**

Arrow functions can have either a "concise body"

```
var fun = z => z + z; //In a concise body, only an expression is needed,and an implicit return is attached.
```

or the usual "block body".

```
var fun = (x,y) => { return x + y;}; //  In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.
```

Since your function is "block body", you must use an explicit return statement.

Comment: hi Shanil. you're right! adding return solved the problem! but doesn't the use of arrow function indicates a return? am i understanding the use of arrow functions wrongly?

Comment: @eugeneoei no it doesn't. Not using the brackets `{}` indicates a return. Ex:`.map((res: Response) => res.json() );`

Comment: @echonax ahhhhh. i get it now. such a fundamental mistake. thanks echonax and @Shanil!